# vbs script what to replace user in a redirectory?

Tags: vbscript

Hi i wanted to know how to replace the user in a directory ? this is my code :

```
Dim oFS,oFl 
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set oFl = oFSO.GetFile("myexe.exe")
oFl.Move "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
```

I dont know what to replace "myusername" to work with any computer. Thanks for the help

Answer (score -2):

If you're looking for the currently logged on user you could pull it from a windows environment variable using the shell object like this.

```vb
Dim objShell : Set objShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
Dim strName : strName = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%USERNAME%" )
```

Or you could pull it from the network object like this.

```vb
Dim objNetwork : Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Dim strName : strName = objNetwork.Name
```

Once you have the username it looks like you're just building a string with the file path it to run an application, which you could use concatenation for.

```vb
objShell.Exec("C:\Users\" & strName & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\myexe.exe")
Set objShell = Nothing
```

Comment: Hi Lucretius and thanks to trying to help me. So i have few problems with this, with the first method this is the error : required object oF1 and with the second method i have this error : this object does not support the property of this method: name. If you have any idea thanks to helping me !

Comment: Sure, just to clarify in your original example are you trying to launch an application "myexe.exe"?   And this file exists as separate files for each individual user?

Comment: In the context yes, it exists for each user, this file is in the same folder where the vbs is.

Comment: ok, another tip if you open Run (Windows Key + R) and type `shell:common startup` you can place the file in a common location for all users so you don't have to worry about user accounts.  In Windows 10 `shell:common startup` points to `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp` which will run for all users.  Is this a better solution?

Comment: Sure but the thing is : it's like a public simple software that people that i'm not knowing can download and that why i need a vbs who put the file into this redirectory automatically

Comment: I'm still not 100% sure of what you're after.  You want a vbscript to automatically copy itself and the executable into a users startup folder?  Can you clarify / elaborate?

Comment: Not more complicated than what you said... I have a folder with an .exe and i need to copy it into the startup folder... and the redirectory link (like C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start )  contain the username that idk how to pass for everyone who download the .exe